# jQuery toggle a class existent above the clicked function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple instances of the HTML below:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-head">
            <a class="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <span>Title</span>

            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-expand icon-spacer" aria-hidden="true" onclick="dosomething();"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function dosomething() {
    .widget above toggleClass('someClassHere');
}
```

I need to be able to click on `dosomething` and have a `class` toggled (added), to the nearest `.widget` above it.

How can I do this in `jQuery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `closest` method of jQuery.

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-expand icon-spacer" aria-hidden="true" onclick="dosomething(this);"></i></a>

function dosomething(obj) {
    $(obj).closest('.widget').toggleClass('someClassHere');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onclick method to fire the event , and add class via jquery after a getSelectedElement

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.icon-spacer').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.widget').toggleClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="widget">
        <div class="widget-head">
            <a class="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <span>Title</span>

            <a href="#" class="fa fa-expand icon-spacer" aria-hidden="true"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```